# How to fix "babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register"?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have followed the instructions in npm official page.
Im not using any TS file

-- in package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "server": "nodemon --exec babel-node --plugins require-context-hook --watch src/server src/server/index.js"
}
```

- in.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["require-context-hook"]
}
```

but still get the error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register'.
```

-- index.js

```
 const context = require.context(
    ".",
    true,
   /^\.\/(?!index\.js).*\.js$/,
    "sync");
```

generates this error :
`ReferenceError: __requireContext is not defined`

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you declare the dependency in your package.json file and install it?

Comment: yes, this is declared as dev dependency in package,json
{ ....    "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0", ...}

Comment: called here if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  require("babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register")();
}

Comment: This error seems to be a typescript error. It's saying that it can't find type definitions for that package. Looking on npm, there doesn't seem to be community-maintained type definitions in Definitely Typed either. This just means you won't get type checking. You might need to configure something in babel to ignore this.

Comment: Im using a JS file. Why typescript is complaining?

Comment: when (during what process which was started by what action) and where does the error occur? Do you have any typescript-related babel-plugins installed?

Comment: my project have only js files, there´s no TS related modules installed. I cant use "require.context" then the error occurs with this message "ReferenceError: __requireContext is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

invert the node environment to the following

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register')()
}
```

essentially replace "development" with "!production"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need it to silence the test files. so you need to import it only in the test environment.

```
{
"plugins":[],
"env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-require-context"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```